# TypeError: Public state variable has override specified but does not override anything

Tags: node.js, solidity, remix, ethers.js, hardhat

**I am getting the following error message when trying to compile AAVE FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol.** **Does this means that ADDRESS_PROVIDER should override a variable in ILendingPoolAddressProvider.sol?**

```
TypeError: Public state variable has override specified but does not override anything.
  --> contracts/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol:11:50:
   |
11 |   ILendingPoolAddressesProvider public immutable override ADDRESSES_PROVIDER;
   |                                                  ^^^^^^^^


TypeError: Public state variable has override specified but does not override anything.
  --> contracts/FlashLoanReceiverBase.sol:12:33:
   |
12 |   ILendingPool public immutable override LENDING_POOL;
```

**My code is as follows,(From AAVE DOCS)**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: agpl-3.0
pragma solidity ^0.6.8;

import { SafeMath } from './SafeMath.sol';
import { IERC20 } from './IERC20.sol';
import { SafeERC20 } from './SafeERC20.sol';
import { IFlashLoanReceiver } from './IFlashLoanReceiver.sol';
import { ILendingPoolAddressesProvider } from './ILendingPoolAddressesProvider.sol';
import { ILendingPool } from './ILendingPool.sol';

/** 
    !!!
    Never keep funds permanently on your FlashLoanReceiverBase contract as they could be 
    exposed to a 'griefing' attack, where the stored funds are used by an attacker.
    !!!
 */
abstract contract FlashLoanReceiverBase is IFlashLoanReceiver {
  using SafeERC20 for IERC20;
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  ILendingPoolAddressesProvider public immutable override ADDRESSES_PROVIDER;
  ILendingPool public immutable override LENDING_POOL;

  constructor(ILendingPoolAddressesProvider provider) public {
    ADDRESSES_PROVIDER = provider;
    LENDING_POOL = ILendingPool(provider.getLendingPool());
  }
}
```

**Trying to compile these documented code is getting a bit tricky. How can there be an error message such as this in documented code? Any advice is welcome.**
**Removing override keyword helps.** **But will it affect performance?**

Answer (score 1):

Override specifier means that there is something in the base class that you intend to override in the child class with. In your case `ADDRESSES_PROVIDER` is just a reference for `ILendingPoolAddressesProvider` interface to call its functions, so you do not need an override specifier here.